# How can I open and define two Excel files in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

As a part of a bigger macro, and need to open and define two workbooks and sheets (I am aware of that I define my worksheets as Variant, I need this for future operations). I get a mistake when I try to set value to SheetRI. What can it be?

```
 Sub compareQRTsAll()

    Dim ActiveWb As Workbook
    Dim ActiveSh As Worksheet
    Dim SheetFasit As Variant
    Dim SheetRI As Variant
    Dim FolderFasit As String
    Dim FileFasit As String
    Dim FolderRI As String
    Dim FileRI As String
    Dim WbFasit As Workbook
    Dim WbRI As Workbook
    Dim WbFasitPath As String
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim nShFasit As Integer
    Dim nShRI As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    i = 2
    j = 6

    Set ActiveWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ActiveSh = ActiveWb.Worksheets(1)
    strRangeToCheck = "A1:AAA1000"
    ActiveSh.Range("A2:D10000").Clear

    FolderFasit = ActiveSh.Range("J6")
    FolderRI = ActiveSh.Range("J7")

    Do While ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) <> ""

    FileFasit = Dir(FolderFasit & "\*" & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) & "*.xls*")
    Set WbFasit = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderFasit & "\" & FileFasit)
    SheetFasit = WbFasit.Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck)
    nShFasit = WbFasit.Sheets.Count

    FileRI = Dir(FolderRI & "\*" & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) & "*.xls*")
    Set WbRI = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderRI & "\" & FileRI)
    SheetRI = WbRI.Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck) '<-------------THIS DOESN'T WORK
    nShRI = WbRI.Sheets.Count


    If nShFasit <> nShRI Then
        MsgBox "QRT " & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) & " has different number of sheets in fasit and in RI. Further check will not be performed"

    ElseIf nShFasit = nShRI And nShFasit = 1 Then

        For iRow = LBound(SheetFasit, 1) To UBound(SheetFasit, 1)
            For iCol = LBound(SheetFasit, 2) To UBound(SheetFasit, 2)
                If SheetFasit(iRow, iCol) = SheetRI(iRow, iCol) Then

                    ' Do nothing.
                Else
                    ActiveSh.Cells(i, 1) = "Check row " & iRow & ", column " & iCol & " in " & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8)
                    ActiveSh.Cells(i, 2) = SheetFasit(iRow, iCol)
                    ActiveSh.Cells(i, 3) = SheetRI(iRow, iCol)
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
     
    End If


    'close workbooks
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ActiveWb Then
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        Next wb

        j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `1` what is the value of "strRangeToCheck" `2` What is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: strRangeToCheck = "A1:AAA1000". And I get 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error)

Comment: Hmm it should work, I do not see any problem with that line

Comment: Check the Whole macro, I updated my post))

Comment: `Set SheetRI = WbRI.Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck)` You have `Set` or you do not have `Set`? The top code doesn't match with the below code

Comment: I was adviced to try with set right now, that is why they do not match. But it makes no difference. Scripts are different because I tried to delete everything that has nothing to do with my problem

Comment: Please confirm if you are using it as an array or a range? `ActiveSh.Cells(i, 3) = SheetRI(iRow, iCol)` shows that you are using it as an array

Comment: As erray, I delete set then

Comment: If you are using as range then you will have to declare them as object and then use `Set`. If you are using as an array then declare them as variant and do not use `Set`

Comment: @MarichkaSakhanda what is the actual name of the file when the error occurs? add `Debug.Print FileRI` what do you get? if it is a `.xls` file then you are facing a compatibility problem.

Comment: This is clear now. Thanks a lot! But macro doesn't work)) Any more ideas?

Comment: Are you working with `xls` files or `xlsx` files? By that I mean the files you open through `Set WbRI = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderRI & "\" & FileRI)`

Comment: Yes, one of the files is xls, another is xlsx. Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes it is, because a worksheet in a `xls` file **does not** have a range `"A1:AAA1000"`. the last column is `"IV"`

Comment: Omg, of course! So stupid. But now I get a mistake here "For iRow = LBound(SheetFasit, 1) To UBound(SheetFasit, 1)" Type mismatch. It was working before...

Comment: This statement works with an array not with a range object. Dont use `Set SheetFasit` if you want to use it as an array, but use `SheetFasit = WbFasit.Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck).Value`

Comment: Everything is perfect now, you can't imagine how much you helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in range strRangeToCheck = "A1:AAA1000". Some of my files are saved as .xls, and there is no AAA column on Excel 2003.

```
    Dim FolderRI As String
    Dim FileRI As String
    Dim WbFasit As Workbook
    Dim WbRI As Workbook
    Dim WbFasitPath As String
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim nShFasit As Integer
    Dim nShRI As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    i = 2
    j = 6

Set ActiveWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ActiveSh = ActiveWb.Worksheets(1)
strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV1000"
ActiveSh.Range("A2:D10000").Clear


' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.

'FolderFasit = InputBox("Enter path to the forder with correct QRTs")
'FolderRI = InputBox("Enter path to the forder with QRTs from RI")
FolderFasit = ActiveSh.Range("J6")
FolderRI = ActiveSh.Range("J7")

Do While ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) <> ""

FileFasit = Dir(FolderFasit & "\*" & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) & "*.xls*")
Set WbFasit = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderFasit & "\" & FileFasit)
SheetFasit = WbFasit.Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck)
nShFasit = WbFasit.Sheets.Count

FileRI = Dir(FolderRI & "\*" & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) & "*.xls*")
Set WbRI = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderRI & "\" & FileRI)
Debug.Print FileRI
SheetRI = WbRI.Worksheets(1).Range(strRangeToCheck)
nShRI = WbRI.Sheets.Count


If nShFasit <> nShRI Then
    MsgBox "QRT " & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8) & " has different number of sheets in fasit and in RI. Further check will not be performed"

    ElseIf nShFasit = nShRI And nShFasit = 1 Then

For iRow = LBound(SheetFasit, 1) To UBound(SheetFasit, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(SheetFasit, 2) To UBound(SheetFasit, 2)
        If SheetFasit(iRow, iCol) = SheetRI(iRow, iCol) Then

            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            ActiveSh.Cells(i, 1) = "Check row " & iRow & ", column " & iCol & " in " & ActiveSh.Cells(j, 8)
            ActiveSh.Cells(i, 2) = SheetFasit(iRow, iCol)
            ActiveSh.Cells(i, 3) = SheetRI(iRow, iCol)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End If


'close workbooks
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If Not wb Is ActiveWb Then
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
Next wb

j = j + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```